# How do I check if params is in a json file and if not throw error response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a json file as below `names.json`. When you append the URL `/list?name=Canada` or `/list?name=CANADA` be it Uppercase or Lowercase, I want to check if the `param[:name]` is inside `names.json` file and throw error if not there.

```
[
  {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Canada"
  },
  {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "Denmark"
  },
  {
      "id": 23,
      "name": "Austria"
  }
]
```

> Here is what I have done but did not work…..

**controller/concerns**

```
require 'json'
JSON_NAMES = 'names.json'.freeze

module NameFileLoader
  class JsonLoader
    def self.json_data_hash
      file = File.read(JSON_NAMES)
      JSON.parse(file)
    end
  end
end
```

**name_controller.rb**

```
def check_name_validity_in_file
    data = NameFileLoader::JsonLoader.json_data_hash
    name = data.each { |item| item['name'] } # The problem is here.
    if name.include?(params[:name])
      { errorCode: 400, message: 'Name provided is not valid' }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’d better cache the JSON once loaded from the file in the first place. Also you probably want to maintain a cached list of allowed countries in the lowercase to compare.

```
module NameFileLoader
  class JsonLoader
    class << self
      def json_data_hash
        @json ||= JSON.parse(File.read(JSON_NAMES))
      end
      def countries
        @countries ||= json_data_hash.map { |h| h['name'].downcase }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now upon receival a parameter you might check it as:

```
if NameFileLoader::JsonLoader.countries.include?(params[:name].downcase)
 ...
end
```

Comment: Is that not supposed to be `.exclude?`. Such that if `params[:name].downcase` is not in `NameFileLoader::JsonLoader.countries` ?

Comment: There in no `exclude?` use `unless` if you want to handle error case only. I showed the approach.